# Java Playframework Internationalization doesn't work

Tags: internationalization, playframework

I used the instructions from here:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/i18n

and created files for different languages.

I call play.i18n.Lang.change method to change the language file, 
and it still takes the captions from the English file ("messages" without a suffix),

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is hard to know from your description exactly what the problem may be, so I have outlined how you should do a multi-lingual app.

There are a number of steps you must follow to get internationalisation to work. Firstly, you must change your `application.conf` file to declare your supported languages.

So, if you are supporting English and French, you would do

```
application.langs=en,fr
```

You must then create the language file for your French translation called `messages.fr`. The English language would just stay in the standard `messages` file. In this new file, add your name value pairs for the key and message.

The way Play processes the messages, is to look first in the locale specific message file first (so for english it would be `messages.en`, which does not exist, and for french it would be `messages.fr`). If the message cannot be found in the locale specific message file, it will look at the global message file. So your global `messages` file acts as the catch all.

Then, in your code, set the language for your particular user, using

```
Lang.change("fr"); // change language to French
```

Remember, that this will save a cookie for the particular user in a PLAY_LANG cookie, so check that this cookie is being created for the user.

Final note, make sure that your files are UTF8 encoded. It causes problems if it is not.

Comment: I do not see the PLAY_LANG cookie,
It is probably part of the problem...
what might be the reason for that?

Comment: Not sure. Does your browser have cookies disabled? I have just run a quick test and using Firebug (in Chrome) I can see the cookie under the document element, and inside there I see PLAY_LANG=fr. Are you manipulating the cookies in any way?

Comment: I checked it, there was no Cookie.

I found the reason:

Comment: in application.conf I had application.lang instead of application.langs (lang instead of langs)  :) 10x for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case I had

```
play.http.session.domain
```

set to something else other than `localhost` while testing.