# Play framework: How can i use "conf/messages"-messages in html-files?

Tags: html, playframework, message

How does it work? Simply with &{messages.message1} when the messages file looks like this:

message1 = hallo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation, use:

```
&{'messages.message1'}
```

(take notice of the single quotes) and add to "messages" file:

```
 messages.message1=your text
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need to know about Internationalisation can be found in [the documentation here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/i18n).

You don't need the `messages` part in your example. If you want to look up `messages1` in your messages file, you just use

```
&{messages1}
```

I'd recommend reading the documentation though, as it explains how to use multiple languages and how to set that up. Also take a look at this example - [Java Playframework Internationalization doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314855/java-playframework-internationalization-doesnt-work/6315067#6315067).